# Associative array keys

Tags: php

I need to create multidimensional arrays with keys for the first level.

```
$aeroports_dates_array = array();
while ( have_rows('aeroports', $product_id) ) : the_row();
    $aeroport = get_sub_field('aeroport');
    $date_array = array();
    while ( have_rows('dates', $product_id) ) : the_row();
        $date = get_sub_field('debut');
        $date_array .= $date;
    endwhile;
    $aeroports_dates_array[$aeroport] .= $date_array;
endwhile;
```

The result is :

```
Array
(
    [titre1] => Arrayvaleur1valeur2
    [titre2] => Arrayvaleur3valeur4
)
```

i am missing something because i need it like that :

```
Array
(
[titre1] => Array
    (
        [0] => valeur1
        [1] => valeur2
    )

[titre2] => Array
    (
        [0] => valeur3
        [1] => valeur4
    )

)
```

Comment: use array_push to add to array, you are doing concatenation

Comment: Change it to `$date_array[] = $date;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are in these lines:

```
$date_array .= $date;
$aeroports_dates_array[$aeroport] .= $date_array;
```

`.=` is the [concatenating assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). It performs string concatenation and store the value in its left-hand side operand.
It is equivalent to:

```
$date_array = $date_array . $date;
```

The string concatenation operator (`.`) expects two strings and it converts its operands to strings before concatenating them. `$date_array` is an array and any array converted to string produces the string `'Array'`. This explains the result you get.

You don't want to concatenate strings but to store values in an array. For this purpose you can use the [square bracket syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) to append an element to the end of the array:

```
$date_array[] = $date;
```

The second incorrect line should be:

```
$aeroports_dates_array[$aeroport] = $date_array;
```

Again, the string concatenation operator does not help on working with arrays. Here `$date_array` is not added at the end of `$aeroports_dates_array` (using the first available numeric key) but it is associated to the value stored in the variable `$aeroport`. This is the regular assignments for array elements, using a key (the value stored in `$date_array` is associated to the key stored in `$aeroport`).